# Material UI pagination show vise versa when I change the direction to rtl

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqVrW.png)

When the direction is ltr the pagination is working correctly, but when I change the direction to rtl
the pagination becomes like above image

I search a lot but did not found a good answer.

Comment: Please add a minimal example code to reproduce your situation. From just your image it's impossible to help you out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.